# Android - Make Chat application using parse.com using my own data

Tags: android, asp.net, parse-platform, chat

I'm very new to ***Android*** development and also very new to ***Parse.com***. I'm developing an application that contains chat. I created my own web service using ***ASP.NET Web API***. I want to use ***Parse.com*** only to handle the messaging operation but with data from my web service. ***Say*** I have two users registered on my web service and I have their ***IDs***. How can I use ***Parse.com*** to make a ***chatting*** between the two users ?
I searched a lot for that and I found some good and powerful tutorials like [This](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-Simple-Chat-Client-with-Parse) and also found [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/) for using Parse but I couldn't understand how to use parse for the purpose I want.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [QuickBlox](https://quickblox.com/) instead and everything works fine. It handles the chatting service and also handles live video streaming.